# SerializableAttribute is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, serialization, xamarin, xsd, xml-serialization

I created a serializeable class using xsd.exe on command prompt and result of the class is like below but VS gives me compile error saying `SerializableAttribute is inaccessible due to its protection level`
and same for `DesignerCategoryAttribute`. I have no idea how to fix this. Can anyone shed me some lights here?

I am using VS2015. Xamarin Cross Platform, Portable application.

All the attributes are public and rss as shown below is the root attribute.

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace RssResponse {        

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
    public partial class rss {

        private rssChannel channelField;

        private decimal versionField;

        private string baseField;
```

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: opps, I didnt think it was platform specific. I updated my question now. class is placed under Xamarin.Forms Project. I know that it has some restrictions but I am not sure about this one

Comment: IIRC, Xamarin doesn't have the `SerializableAttribute` available; I think `DataContract` is used instead. It's also possible that perhaps you may not even need the `SerializableAttribute` for your usage anyway, but I'm not positive. Try removing it and give it a shot. EDIT: Well, maybe it is there now? https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.SerializableAttribute/ Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: It looks like that `SerializableAttribute` is not supported in the Portable version of Xamarin https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22514/portable-class-library-and-serialization-issue

Comment: Actually all answers are correct here. as @ChrisSinclair said, I didnt even need the attribute declaration. It will just serialize fine using xmlserializer.